# Suggestions for improving Bigtable/HBase/Spark workflow (economically)

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a rather small dataset (5~gb, 1.5 million rows), currently stored in Bigtable, and accessed through the HBase API (Scala), for the purpose of doing data analytics with Spark (dataproc).

However, I'm also on a tight budget, and the Bigtable cost is rather high (2~ USD/hour), so what I ended up doing is deleting and recreating the Bigtable cluster whenever I need it.

The obvious drawback is that it takes quite a while to populate a fresh cluster, due to the nature of my data. It's all stored in a single big textfile as JSON, and it takes 40~ minutes to populate the cluster.

So what I'm asking is whether there are better way to execute this, like implementing some kind of backup/snapshot routine? Or simply not using Bigtable at all. I couldn't find any other HDFS alternatives in the Google Cloud platform.

*It should be noted that I'm rather fresh to the world of Hadoop and big data, so excuse my ignorance if I'm missing the obvious.*

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you haven't seen it, we show how to use [Cloud Bigtable with Dataproc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/wordcount-mapreduce). It should be easy to spin up a job to populate your Bigtable quickly if that's what you wish.

Bigtable is really designed for 1T or larger databases.  At the 5GB size, you might wish to consider [Memcache](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/). With Redis, you would only need to load your data once, then you could save the disk when you spin down your instance / cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally (if it fits your use case and you don't need the database aspects of Bigtable), you can run Hadoop or Spark jobs (using [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) if you'd like) directly over files in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), which will be substantially cheaper than storing the data in Bigtable.

See [Google Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Consider importing the json once, and then exporting the data to sequence files via hadoop, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-importing.  The sequence file format that hadoop uses is likely to be more efficient than json.